# Is there really "no registration required"?

Tags: support, new-users

When I am not logged in, I see this on the front page:

[image]

Sounds good. But when I hit the "ask a question" button, I see this:

[image]

Isn't that a contradiction? Maybe people find it dubious if there's *no registration required* yet they have to sign up in order to use the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Asked and answered on Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120707/clarify-the-no-registration-required-message).

The gist of it is that the original meaning of *no registration* was that other, similar Q&A sites required you to register *just to **see** the answers*; this is not the case here. You should be able to answer questions without registering.

Note that this is more explicitly stated in the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/) (specifically the [Why should I create an account?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) under the [My Account](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/account) header)

> Registration is not required to participate on Stack Exchange; you can read, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like on Wikipedia. There are some things you won’t be able to do on the site without registering, however, such as vote. Registering is easy, and once logged in, you can gain other key privileges by earning reputation.

The original policy *was* no registration required, but the original site ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) was receiving [several *thousand* questions per day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) (QPD), many of which were *low quality*. So the creator of the site, [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), changed it to require registration for *asking* questions (in attempts to stave off the sheer number of bad questions). The comment thread under Jeff's answer is worth the read.

Comment: The question has no accepted answer. The answer with the most up votes concludes that this should be changed. This was 3 years ago. Apparently nothing happened ever since.

Comment: Correct, it was not accepted (not entirely a necessity, IMO) and it probably should be changed. But it seems it is not important enough to warrant the time investment in changing the banner. [This Mother Meta Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107152/230312) says *why* questioners require registration & reiterates the answerers don't need to register.

Comment: And if you go [to the FAQ page on *Why should I create an account*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) it says more explicitly that there are some things you *can* do w/o registering and somethings you *cannot* do w/o registering.

Comment: The problem on Stack Overflow wasn't the volume of questions, but the volume of _low quality_ questions. Registration is a first barrier and filters out _some_ of those.

Comment: @Oded: Thank you for that point, I've added the clarification.

Comment: Additionally, most Stack Exchange sites still don't require registration for asking questions. Only the ones where much of the incoming questions were very low quality and that have requested it do (5 out of ~140, physics being one of the 5).